# PHP upload file change name

Tags: php

I got an upload script and must to change file name first of uploading.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
$fileName    = $_POST['articleSlug'];
$storeFolder = '../uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                      

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

}
?>
```

I must to use the `$fileName` variable to change filename, but when I change the $targetFile variable it doesn't upload the file anymore, so I've reverted my code to the moment was working, can you please help me to find how to replace the original file name using the variable content?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just change $targetFile

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: Did you try it? Or are you just asking SO to do it and tell you it works.

Comment: I've tried already to change the $targetFile value, but the file was not uploaded, so I revert all my changes and post this working example. Edit I can't understand why I got -4 votes but thanks!

Comment: you never bothered checking if the upload OR move were successful. `$_FILES` being set is meaningless. failed uploads can/will set data in $_FILES. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason, and `move_uploaded_file` returns true/false as well. You never check ANY of that, so you're simply ASSUMING nothing ever goes wrong. a very bad attitude to have.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, can you please provide an example on how to use the ['error'] parameter? I'm using this script on Dropzone.js that will upload file without report any success/failure and I don't know how to use the result parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

> $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

to

> $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']));
>
> $targetFile =  $targetPath. fileName . '.' . $ext;

Comment: Thanks it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely error is that changing $targetFile with $fileName, you're trying to write the file to a place where you do not have sufficient permissions.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
 <?php

    $ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
    $fileName    = $_POST['articleSlug'];
    $storeFolder = '../uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                      

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  

    $targetFile =  $targetPath . $fileName; 



    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

}
?>
```

Also "move_uploaded_file" throws warnings when somethings goes wrong. You can visualize this warnings with the following lines at begining of the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Finally you can do a vardump of the two possible destination and compare them to detect whats going on.

```
var_dump($targetPath . $fileName, $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']);
```